# Ways to identify if music has vocal timbres in it?

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum, signal-detection, sound, speech-recognition

The human voice is singular because it has a specific frequency spectrum and fast transitions between vowels and consonants.

What are good and computationally fast ways to detect if there is probably a voice contained in a noisy music, the amount of the song where there is vocals, and the type of vocals in different kinds of music, that perhaps have beats and guitars and other sounds mixed into the vocal?

Answer (score 1):

Scalable audio separation with light Kernel Additive Modelling

http://www.loria.fr/~aliutkus/kaml/

Comment: Any chance for getting a descriptive answer?

Comment: In addition it's hardly addressing the question. Vocal detection and source separation are only superficially related.

Comment: The linked tool separates vocals from beats and other music based on spectral patterns of those, it is exactly what author needs. You can also check examples here http://www.loria.fr/~aliutkus/kam/

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev, either you or me are misunderstanding the original question. In my eyes what he needs is not any form of separation, but merely presence detection of voice. Separating different sources provides little help there and overcomplicates the whole process. Even with separate sources, you'd still have to find some sort of classifier that tells you if one of these sources is voice. There is no reason to assume that such a classifier could not operate on the mixed source signal. In fact, a separation of different vocal features into different sources might make it harder.

Comment: Dear @Jazzmaniac, if you are interested in this technology you are welcome to visit the link and check the publication to learn how it finds voice source based on voice spectrotemporal properties. Method also detects beat sources and melody sources. The classifier is not required.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev, you're missing the point. Demixing gives you a list of independent sources, but does not tell if you if one of them is a human vocalist. That is what the OP is asking for, not the separation of the vocal.

Comment: In this study, natural sounds such as the human voice are simply assumed to have smooth variations in their PSD, along time or along frequency, e.g. during voiced or voiceless parts, respectively. Since this assumption is rather loose and is valid for a large variety of signals, we call it a weak model for natural sounds. Formally, such a model considers that fj (l) and fj (l′) are close whenever l and l′ are close either along time or frequency. This is achieved by choosing the cross-like kernel depicted in figure 8(d).

Comment: Also see the section D. Voice extraction performance in the paper http://www.loria.fr/~aliutkus/kam/KAM.pdf

Comment: Thanks alot for those leads, so KAM checks a spectrogram for groups of sounds that have similar variations in amplitude and frequency and defines them as instruments or something. i will have to ask a question about that because it's very advanced (sounds are not constant variation across all their harmonics, that would be easy)...    Having completed that, the Vocal recognition is a reverse engineer of vocal physical modelling synthesis rules, perhaps.

Comment: The field that you refer to is "audio source seperation" the document that you refer is a single research publication. The section D for KAM.pdf is a 404. I can't find info on time-frequency identification of voice.